# Is $\mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$ first countable?

Tags: general-topology

Give $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ the box topology. Let $\mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$ denote the subspace consisting of sequences of rationals that end in an infinite string of 0's.

I'm thinking that since $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ has the box topology, we're going to run into issues when tying to construct a countable basis for some sequence in $\mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$, but I'm having a hard time formalizing things. Any advice?

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\Bbb R^\omega$ with the box topology is not first countable? The same argument works for your subspace.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. Oddly, I didn't really think of that but the argument does work perfectly.

Comment: You’re welcome!